# Multiple searches in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to sum the last cell in each row if two of the columns in the row (Period and Type) match the user inputs through the userform. I was going to use a `For Each` loop with a source and a target but I don't think you can have more than one target. For the targets, I declared string variables (`Period` and `Type`) that stores the user input. I have the following code so far but can't figure out how to incorporate the second column to match up before summing the last cell as well as summing the last cell.

```
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Period)

j = 2
For Each c In Source.Range("E2:E100000")
    If c = Period Then 'And Type
        'Sum code
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: I am having a hard time visualizing your requirement, would you mind showing how your data is organized?

Answer (score 0):

First off, it sounds like something that a simple formula would be able to take care of.

Using actual values for `Period` an `Type`, and assuming columns F and Z are the Type and last column (to sum) respectfully, the formula would look like this:

`=SumIFS("Z2:Z100000","E2:E100000",Period,"F2:F100000",Type)`

Let's talk about your code now...

- I don't see a variable or cell to store the sum in.
- Target worksheet should have quotes around then name
  `.Worksheets("Period")`
  *(but then again I don't know what this Target Worksheet is even used for.)*
- What is `j` doing? If you want to know the row, the drop the `For Each` and use `For j = 2 to 100000` for everything.  Then reference the cells like this:

`If Source.Cells(j,5) = Period And Source.Cells(j,6) = Type Then Sum = Sum + Source.Cells(j,26)`

- The other option would be to use `Offset` to shift over columns like:
  `And C.Offset(0,1) = Type Then Sum = Sum + C.Offset(0,21)`
- Do you know for a fact that the data goes to exactly row 100,000? I doubt it; So instead, find the last row and use that:  `LastRow = Source.Range("E" & Source.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`
- Also, you never mention what you are summing? Days, Integers, Real(Double) numbers...

Putting it together, it would look like this:

```
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Row As Long, LastRow as Long
Dim Sum As Double

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
With Source
    LastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Row = 2 to LastRow
        If .Cells(Row,5) = Period And .Cells(Row,6) = Type Then Sum = Sum + .Cells(Row,26)
    Next
End With
```

Or the faster way, of copying the Data to a Variant (once), and never talking to the sheet again until you have to output a sum:

```
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim vData 'As Variant
Dim Row As Long, LastRow as Long
Dim Sum As Double

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
With Source
    LastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    vData = .Range("A1:Z" & LastRow).Value2    
    ' I started at Row 1 to make vData align better with the sheet
    ' and remove confusion with different offsets in the for loop.
End With
For Row = 2 to LastRow
    If vData(Row,5) = Period And vData(Row,6) = Type Then Sum = Sum + vData(Row,26)
Next
```

Hopefully I understood you problem and the I didn't make any mistakes (as I didn't test the code).